# Android retrofit set value null

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit

I have started learning Api consumption in android .I used retrofit but i am getting error.I have following Api response

```
{
  "matches": [
    {
      "unique_id": 1122277,
      "date": "2018-01-13T00:00:00.000Z",
      "team-2": "India",
      "team-1": "South Africa",
      "type": "Test",
      "dateTimeGMT": "2018-01-13T08:00:00.000Z",
      "squad": true,
      "toss_winner_team": "South Africa",
      "matchStarted": true
    },
    {
      "unique_id": 1116902,
      "team-2": "Namibia Under-19s",
      "team-1": "England Under-19s",
      "type": "YouthODI",
      "date": "2018-01-14T00:00:00.000Z",
      "dateTimeGMT": "2018-01-14T21:30:00.000Z",
      "squad": true,
      "toss_winner_team": "Namibia Under-19s",
      "winner_team": "England Under-19s",
      "matchStarted": true
    }
      ],
  "v": "1",
  "ttl": 68,
  "provider": {
    "source": "Various",
    "url": "https://cricapi.com/",
    "pubDate": "2018-01-16T16:28:19.313Z"
  },
  "creditsLeft": 250
}
```

I have following code

Model Class

```
 public class NewMatchList {

    List<MatchList> matchList;

    public NewMatchList(List<MatchList> matchList) {
        this.matchList = matchList;
    }

    public List<MatchList> getMatchList() {
        return matchList;
    }

    public void setMatchList(List<MatchList> matchList) {
        this.matchList = matchList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString();
    }

    public class MatchList{
        private int id;
        private String date;
        private String teamOne;
        private String teamTwo;
        private String matchType;
        private String dateTimeGMT;
        private boolean squad;
        private String tossWinnerTeam;
        private String winnerTeam;
        private boolean matchStarted;


        public MatchList(int id, String date, String teamOne, String teamTwo, String matchType, String dateTimeGMT, boolean squad, String tossWinnerTeam, String winnerTeam, boolean matchStarted) {
            this.id = id;
            this.date = date;
            this.teamOne = teamOne;
            this.teamTwo = teamTwo;
            this.matchType = matchType;
            this.dateTimeGMT = dateTimeGMT;
            this.squad = squad;
            this.tossWinnerTeam = tossWinnerTeam;
            this.winnerTeam = winnerTeam;
            this.matchStarted = matchStarted;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.toString();
        }
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        public void setDate(String date) {
            this.date = date;
        }

        public String getTeamOne() {
            return teamOne;
        }

        public void setTeamOne(String teamOne) {
            this.teamOne = teamOne;
        }

        public String getTeamTwo() {
            return teamTwo;
        }

        public void setTeamTwo(String teamTwo) {
            this.teamTwo = teamTwo;
        }

        public String getMatchType() {
            return matchType;
        }

        public void setMatchType(String matchType) {
            this.matchType = matchType;
        }

        public String getDateTimeGMT() {
            return dateTimeGMT;
        }

        public void setDateTimeGMT(String dateTimeGMT) {
            this.dateTimeGMT = dateTimeGMT;
        }

        public boolean isSquad() {
            return squad;
        }

        public void setSquad(boolean squad) {
            this.squad = squad;
        }

        public String getTossWinnerTeam() {
            return tossWinnerTeam;
        }

        public void setTossWinnerTeam(String tossWinnerTeam) {
            this.tossWinnerTeam = tossWinnerTeam;
        }

        public String getWinnerTeam() {
            return winnerTeam;
        }

        public void setWinnerTeam(String winnerTeam) {
            this.winnerTeam = winnerTeam;
        }

        public boolean isMatchStarted() {
            return matchStarted;
        }

        public void setMatchStarted(boolean matchStarted) {
            this.matchStarted = matchStarted;
        }
    }

}
```

Main Activity i have

```
 ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<NewMatchList> apiList=apiService.getNewMatchListCallListCall(API_KEY);
        apiList.enqueue(new Callback<NewMatchList>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<NewMatchList> call, Response<NewMatchList> response) {
                   NewMatchList  newMatchList=response.body();
                Log.d("ApiCall",response.toString());
                Log.d("ApiCall_22",newMatchList.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"inside",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<NewMatchList> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("ApiCall_Error",t.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

Interface i have

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("matches")
    Call<NewMatchList> getNewMatchListCallListCall(@Query("apikey") String apiKey);

}
```

But every time in log i am getting success with following result .

```
 com.example.project.volleyretroprofit.Model.NewMatchList@4195b478
```

if i try to access `response.body().getMatchList()` then null pointer exception
Can any one help me where i am wrong

Updated

```
public class ApiClient {
   public static final String BASE_URL = "http://cricapi.com/api/";

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

**Updated Match.java**

```
public class Match {

    @SerializedName("unique_id")
    @Expose
    private Integer uniqueId;
    @SerializedName("date")
    @Expose
    private String date;
    @SerializedName("team-2")
    @Expose
    private String team2;
    @SerializedName("team-1")
    @Expose
    private String team1;
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("dateTimeGMT")
    @Expose
    private String dateTimeGMT;
    @SerializedName("squad")
    @Expose
    private Boolean squad;
    @SerializedName("toss_winner_team")
    @Expose
    private String tossWinnerTeam;
    @SerializedName("matchStarted")
    @Expose
    private Boolean matchStarted;
    @SerializedName("winner_team")
    @Expose
    private String winnerTeam;

    public Integer getUniqueId() {
        return uniqueId;
    }

    public void setUniqueId(Integer uniqueId) {
        this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTeam2() {
        return team2;
    }

    public void setTeam2(String team2) {
        this.team2 = team2;
    }

    public String getTeam1() {
        return team1;
    }

    public void setTeam1(String team1) {
        this.team1 = team1;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getDateTimeGMT() {
        return dateTimeGMT;
    }

    public void setDateTimeGMT(String dateTimeGMT) {
        this.dateTimeGMT = dateTimeGMT;
    }

    public Boolean getSquad() {
        return squad;
    }

    public void setSquad(Boolean squad) {
        this.squad = squad;
    }

    public String getTossWinnerTeam() {
        return tossWinnerTeam;
    }

    public void setTossWinnerTeam(String tossWinnerTeam) {
        this.tossWinnerTeam = tossWinnerTeam;
    }

    public Boolean getMatchStarted() {
        return matchStarted;
    }

    public void setMatchStarted(Boolean matchStarted) {
        this.matchStarted = matchStarted;
    }

    public String getWinnerTeam() {
        return winnerTeam;
    }

    public void setWinnerTeam(String winnerTeam) {
        this.winnerTeam = winnerTeam;
    }

}
```

**updated NewMatchList.java**

```
   public class NewMatchList {

    @SerializedName("matches")
    @Expose
    List<Match> matchList;

    public NewMatchList(List<Match> matchList) {
        this.matchList = matchList;
    }

    public List<Match> getMatchList() {
        return matchList;
    }

    public void setMatchList(List<Match> matchList) {
        this.matchList = matchList;
    }

 }
```

Comment: Can you please post the code where you create the client?

Comment: @Eselfar.updated question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your keys name should match the member variables name in model class.

do something like this

```
public class NewMatchList {

@SerializedName("matches")
@Expose
List<MatchList> matchList;

public NewMatchList(List<MatchList> matchList) {
    this.matchList = matchList;
}

public List<MatchList> getMatchList() {
    return matchList;
}

public void setMatchList(List<MatchList> matchList) {
    this.matchList = matchList;
}

public class MatchList{
    @SerializedName("unique_id")
    @Expose
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("date")
    @Expose
    private String date;
    @SerializedName("team-1")
    @Expose
    private String teamOne;
    @SerializedName("team-2")
    @Expose
    private String teamTwo;
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String matchType;
    @SerializedName("dateTimeGMT")
    @Expose
    private String dateTimeGMT;
    @SerializedName("squad")
    @Expose
    private boolean squad;
    @SerializedName("toss_winner_team")
    @Expose
    private String tossWinnerTeam;
    @SerializedName("matchStarted")
    @Expose
    private String winnerTeam;
    @SerializedName("winner_team")
    @Expose
    private boolean matchStarted;


    public MatchList(int id, String date, String teamOne, String teamTwo, String matchType, String dateTimeGMT, boolean squad, String tossWinnerTeam, String winnerTeam, boolean matchStarted) {
        this.id = id;
        this.date = date;
        this.teamOne = teamOne;
        this.teamTwo = teamTwo;
        this.matchType = matchType;
        this.dateTimeGMT = dateTimeGMT;
        this.squad = squad;
        this.tossWinnerTeam = tossWinnerTeam;
        this.winnerTeam = winnerTeam;
        this.matchStarted = matchStarted;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTeamOne() {
        return teamOne;
    }

    public void setTeamOne(String teamOne) {
        this.teamOne = teamOne;
    }

    public String getTeamTwo() {
        return teamTwo;
    }

    public void setTeamTwo(String teamTwo) {
        this.teamTwo = teamTwo;
    }

    public String getMatchType() {
        return matchType;
    }

    public void setMatchType(String matchType) {
        this.matchType = matchType;
    }

    public String getDateTimeGMT() {
        return dateTimeGMT;
    }

    public void setDateTimeGMT(String dateTimeGMT) {
        this.dateTimeGMT = dateTimeGMT;
    }

    public boolean isSquad() {
        return squad;
    }

    public void setSquad(boolean squad) {
        this.squad = squad;
    }

    public String getTossWinnerTeam() {
        return tossWinnerTeam;
    }

    public void setTossWinnerTeam(String tossWinnerTeam) {
        this.tossWinnerTeam = tossWinnerTeam;
    }

    public String getWinnerTeam() {
        return winnerTeam;
    }

    public void setWinnerTeam(String winnerTeam) {
        this.winnerTeam = winnerTeam;
    }

    public boolean isMatchStarted() {
        return matchStarted;
    }

    public void setMatchStarted(boolean matchStarted) {
        this.matchStarted = matchStarted;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: @vikas.Thanks .still i am not getting result .getting volleyretroprofit.Model.NewMatchList@41964050

Comment: hi @vision can you post your json you are getting from response into this utility it will convert the model for you correctly. im sure we are still something missing in mapping only. try it let me know.
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: @vikas.i have updated my pojo class as per your suggestion .check my question.still same thanks

Comment: you are mapping the inner model or class correctly but are using the same for list matches.

Comment: @vikas.sorry i didnt got your point.since i am new to android .not much aware of this library too

Comment: i have updated the models in your question can you try now same as in last two updated model.

Comment: @vikas.thanks for the effort.still am getting same i tihnk i have problem with the log .

Comment: ApiCall_22: com.example.project.volleyretroprofit.Model.NewMatchList@41964d80

Comment: it depends what are trying to print in log newMatchList.toString() will always give you what you have commented above. so get a particular field instead to check if data is coming. like
Log.d("ApiCall_22"," the size is "+newMatchList.size());
this should give you the size of two or something like.try again this one.

Comment: @vikas.ya size is returning perfectly .how i can access individual property

Comment: great this means it's working fine just call like this one.
Log.d("ApiCall_22"," The team is " + newMatchList.get(0).getTeam1());

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163268/discussion-between-vision-and-vikas-kumar).